# Assigning random letters to several jbuttons

Tags: java, arrays, swing, random, jbutton

I need to have 4 random letters assigned to 4 random jbuttons out of 16. What I currently have is putting the same random letter on all 16 buttons. Thanks for the help!

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GameG implements Runnable {

    public static JButton jba;
    public static JPanel jp;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        JFrame jf = new JFrame("Keybricks");
        Random rnd = new Random();

        jp = new JPanel();

        jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 1));

        jf.setSize(300, 600);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setResizable(false);
        jf.add(jp);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        char[] letter = new char[1];
        for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
            char c = (char) (rnd.nextInt(26) + (65));
            letter[i] = c;
        }

        String text = new String(letter);
        JButton[] buttons = new JButton[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
            JButton jba = new JButton(text);
            jba.addKeyListener(new KeyL());
            jp.add(jba);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you split up your code in a) a method that generates four random letters (returned e.g. as list) and b) a method that selects randomly four JButtons and returns them as list, too?If you have it this way, you only need to iterate over the lists and assign the letter to the corresponding button. Not nice, but a simple approach.

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener with a JButton, use a ActionListerner, if your "really" need to know when a given key is typed for a button, then you should be using a key binding instead. As to your question, generate a random boolean (0 or 1) or use Random, when true AND if the count is less then 4, generate a random character and update the count

Comment: Would also recommend using the same `Random` object throughout. While still variable, the initial values of four separate `Random` objects can be less-than-(pseudo)random.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Where would it throw the exception?  It looks like everything goes up to it's max bounds and not past.  Although I do admit that the method of generating a random char is kind of funky, but should work

Comment: @phflack Okay, I tripped over `char[] letter = new char[1];` and didn't realise they were using `letter.length`, thought they were using some other limit

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems with your code:

```
char[] letter = new char[1];
for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
    char c = (char) (rnd.nextInt(26) + (65));
    letter[i] = c;
}
```

My assumption is that you want to generate and store a list of random letters. With the above code you only allocate an array of characters of size 1. Thus, your problem first begins here because you only really generate and store one random letter (your `for` loop terminates after iterating once since `letter.length` equals 1). Instead, you probably want to either initialize the character array to the number of buttons you want to display (ie: 16) or, if you don't know how many buttons you'll have, then you'll want to store the data in a `List<Character>` and [`add`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-E-) the randomly generated characters into it so that they can be recalled later.

Your next problem is your conversion to String via:

```
String text = new String(letter);
```

If you read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String-char:A-) for the above where `letter` represents a character array:

> Allocates a new String so that it represents the sequence of characters currently contained in the character array argument. The contents of the character array are copied; subsequent modification of the character array does not affect the newly created string.

In other words, even if the first part of your code correctly generated a random array of characters, you have now created a single string that contains the concatenation of every character in the array.

Instead, to convert a character to a String, you can actually just do something as simple as the following:

```
String.valueOf('a');
```

So bringing it all together, you need to first be generating and storing the random characters correctly, you then need to correctly convert the characters into the String types, and then you need to recall the values so that they can be assigned to each button.